# Yii Framework form submit button showing error

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am getting an error
`Fatal error: Call to a member function hasErrors() on a non-object in F:\xampp\yii\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php on line 2253` 
when trying to access the url `http://localhost/happybox/index.php/site/cart/3`. The code of my view file cart.php is:

```
Hello, <?php echo ucwords(Yii::app()->user->name); ?>,<br/>
This is your cart<br/>
Click on Order to Place and Order.<br/>

<?php 
$Orders = Orders::model()->findAll(array(
    'select'=>'products_id',
    'condition'=>'users_id=:id && type=:type',
    'params'=>array(':id'=>Yii::app()->user->id, ':type'=>'cart'),
));

?>
<?php 
if($Orders){
    foreach ($Orders as $order) {
    echo '<br/>'.$order->products->title.'<br/>'.$order->products->description.'<br/>';

    }
}else{
    echo 'Your Cart is Empty';
}

?><br/><br/>

<?php 
if($Orders){
   $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('id'=>'order-form')); 
   echo $form->hiddenField($model,'users_id',array('value'=>Yii::app()->user->id)); 
   echo CHtml::submitButton('Confirm Your Order'); 
   $this->endWidget(); 
}
?>
```

The code of my controller function is

```
public function actionCart($id){
    if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
        $this->redirect('login');
    }else{
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        if(isset($_POST['Orders']))
        {        
        //do something
        }
        $this->render('cart', array('model'=>$model));
    }
}
```

Can someone please point out the error in this code, Its very very important for me. Please help.

Comment: like Telvin has answered, you need to fix this line: `$model = $model=$this->loadModel($id);` to `$model = $this->loadModel($id);`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: I did that.. but the problem is intact..

Comment: does your view render up untill a certain point? In other words, does the error only occur where you start your form (here: `$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('id'=>'order-form'));` )? Or does the page not render at all?

Comment: the page renders upto a certain point. I understood the error, the code `$model = $this->loadModel($id);` returns mutiple rows from the model `Orders` as the loadModel function fetches rows in the Orders table where `users_id=$id`.
I have recognised the error but I dont understand how to sort it out as I am not that proficient in Yii.

Also, lets say this problem is solved, then I want to change the `type` column in the same Orders table whose `users_id=$id`.
Can you please tell me how to use the update feature to do the same.
PS: There is one other row called `products_id` in `Orders` model.

Comment: `$model` is supposed to be an instance of a single Orders model. Could you please try changing `$model=$this->loadModel($id);` to `$model = Orders::model()->findByPk($id)` ?

Comment: `$id` is not corresponding to the PK in Orders table. It is corresponding to the `users_id` FK in Orders table with an additional condition that 'type' column of the fetched model should have a particular value 'cart'.
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered the same bug, when I created a hiddenField inside a widget. This way it worked:

```
echo $form->hiddenField(
    **YourModelName::model()**,
    'users_id',
    array('value' => Yii::app()->user->id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$model = $model=$this->loadModel($id);` Fix this line in your code and `var_dump` $model to see what it returned, check if it was null or something not CActiveRecord

Comment: I did that, still the problem is not solved. Also, $model is not null and belongs to CActiveRecord.